# most recent 3 purchase dates of a customer in tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to do tableau calculation where I have orderdate like this:

```
orderdate
01/02/2016---first orderdate
02/01/2016
06/17/2016
07/01/2016---want to calculate this for a cuustomer
08/04/2016----last orderdate
```

I know that we can calculate first and last order date by using a min and max. But I want to calculate day previous to last orderdate. Means I want last 3 orderdates of customer as most recent purchased dates.

Answer (score 0):

the index() and last() functions should be able to help you.. the sorting and fields you are displaying could get tricky.. assume you have just [orderdate] as a discrete dimension on your row shelf, adding this as a calculated field should hopefully help you come up with something that meets your needs:

```
if last()<3 then sum([Amt]) else null end
```

try adding index() and last() functions to your row shelf to see the values calculated by these functions to assist you